# Where can I find resources about the SQL Server Express LocalDB (Local) database that you can create in asp.net dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Visual Studio is giving me the option to add a service dependency to my asp.net project. I am currently using the in-memory EFCore database while prototyping, but I want to migrate and I'm looking at my options. Is there anywhere where I can find resources and documentation for how to use the local SQL server express database, or are there better local options?

Comment: do you want to migrate ef core database to sql server express Local DB? By the way, what is your in-memory EF Core database? Is it the same as [EF Core In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)?

Comment: Yes, that is the database I've been using